# Overloading Indexer Not Working

Tags: c#, collections, indexing, this

I have a custom collection and I want to overload the indexer. My problem is that I get a compile time error even though the signatures are different.

```
        public HeaderLine this[LineNumber lineNum]
       {
           get
           {
               return (HeaderLine)InnerList[(int)lineNum - 1];
           }
            set
            {
                InnerList[(int)lineNum] = (HeaderLine)value;
            }
        }


        public HeaderLine this[int lineNum]
        {
            get
            {
                return (HeaderLine)InnerList[lineNum - 1];
            }
            set
            {
                InnerList[lineNum - 1] = (HeaderLine)value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And when I simply try to implement this:

```
MessageBox.Show(myDatafile.Header[3].Description);
```

These are the errors:

> **ERROR** The best overloaded method match for 'XXX.Header.this[XXX.LineNumber]' has some invalid arguments
>
> **ERROR** Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int' to 'XXX.LineNumber'

I'm starting to think that you can't overload an indexer multiple times? Or what am I doing wrong where this doesn't work. **I KNOW WORKAROUNDS** such as XXX.Header[(LineNumber)myIntegerValue], but I'd really like it to be VERY novice friendly. Thank you.

**EDIT** `LineNumber` is an `enum`

**LONG EDIT** Here is my custom collection class (sorry if too long I didn't know what would be necessary)

```
   namespace XXX
   {
     public class HeaderLines : CollectionBase
     {
       public void Add(HeaderLine newHeaderLine)
       {
           List.Add((HeaderLine)newHeaderLine);
       }

       public void Remove(HeaderLine newHeaderLine)
       {
           List.Remove((HeaderLine)newHeaderLine);
       }

       public HeaderLine this[LineNumber lineNum]
       {
           get
           {
               return (HeaderLine)InnerList[(int)lineNum - 1];
           }
           set
           {
               InnerList[(int)lineNum] = (HeaderLine)value;
           }   
       }

       public HeaderLine this[int lineNum]
       {
           get
           {
               return (HeaderLine)InnerList[lineNum - 1];
           }
           set
           {
               InnerList[lineNum - 1] = (HeaderLine)value;
           }
       }
   }
```

}

```
namespace XXX
{
   public class HeaderLine
   {

       public string Description { get; set; }
    
       public override string ToString()
       {
           return Description;
       }
        
   }
```

}

**EDIT**: I feel so sorry to waste everyones time. I found my problem and it was a stupid mistake. I'm just beginning to teach myself through reading. What happened was the class that held the collection didn't correctly implement the indexers. Sorry.

Comment: Could you post a short but *complete* example which we can all compile too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most definitely *can* overload indexers (and plenty of system types do so). Here's an example which compiles without problem:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    public string this[string text]
    {
        get { return text; }
    }

    public int this[int number]
    {
        get { return number; }
    }
}

class FooHolder
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var holder = new FooHolder { Foo = new Foo() };

        int x = holder.Foo[10];
        string y = holder.Foo["hello"];
    }
}
```

See whether you can come up with a similar short but complete program which fails, and we can work out why. At the moment there are too many unknowns to easily diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that again shows multiple indexers, but also shows it doing the enum conversion like you are doing and it works, you can copy and paste this into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to run it.

We need more info about your code.

```
public void Main()
{
    DaClass thing = new DaClass();

    Console.WriteLine(thing[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(thing[Magic.Two]);


}

public class DaClass
{
    private List<string> stuff = new List<string>{"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"};
    public string this[Magic m]
    {
        get{return stuff[(int)m];}
        set{stuff[(int)m] = value;}
    }

    public string this[int i]
    {
        get{return stuff[i];}
        set{stuff[i] = value;}
    }
}
//Results
//Item2
//Item3
```